# Class byte para armazenamento de Imagem em C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

sou novo na programação estou criando uma aplicação para Hotelaria e nessa aplicação teremos várias imagens para cada hotel, criei o seguinte código:

```
public class hotel : BaseClass
    public List<Image> Images { get; set;}
```

Ai dentro do arquivo image.cs

```
public class Image
    public Byte Image {get; get;}
```

arquivo HotelImage.cd

```
public class HotelImage : BaseClass
    public Guid HotelID {get; set;}
    public Hotel Hotels {get; set;}
    public Guid ImageId {get; set;}
    public Image Images {get; set;}
```

dentro do context.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HotelImage>.HasKey(sc => new { sc.HotelId, sc.ImagemId});
```

Mas na hora de gerar o BD com o Add-Migration e Update Database ele não cria um campo para armazenar imagem. Tem algo errado nesse código

Comment: Seria porque a propriedade `Image` foi declarada com dois `get` ao invés de um `get` e um `set`?

Comment: Boa, deixa eu atualizar isso, ñ tinha percebido este erro, já dou retorno se deu certo

Comment: Não deu certo também, achei outro erro no meu código, public class hotel : BaseClass
    public List<Image> Images { get; set;} o correto seria: public class hotel : BaseClass
    public List<HotelImage> Images { get; set;} e correção no context da seguinte forma  modelBuilder.Entity<HotelImage>()
                .HasRequired(bc => bc.Hotels)
                .WithMany(b => b.Images)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.HotelId);